# When I run `CompleteableFuture` each time, does it run in the same thread pool just different threads?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am trying to draw a diagram explaining how multi-threading works in my system and how I would optimize the latency of my system due to blocking methods.

I use Java 8. In my code, I call CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(...).get() and CompleteableFuture.runAsync(...).get() which spins up a new thread and I'm not very familiar with:

Which thread are these being run in? Is it an entirely different thread pool each time I call supplyAsync or runAsync or is it the same thread pool just different threads? Is the main thread in that thread pool? Or is the main thread by itself and these are run in separate thread pools?
Is get blocking in main thread aka I have to wait for the CompleteableFuture to complete until I can get the result?
Let's just say in my runAsync I have two methods. One is checkIfCapable and the second is doIt. checkIfCapable should not be blocking, but doIt should be blocking because I wait for the result from doIt in order to determine whether or not I should call a separate CompleteableFuture in a new thread. So essentially I'm thinking of a callback, I start a new thread that only does checkifCapable if it works, then send a callback to main thread, until then, main thread just continues until it needs to determine doIt.

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are not calling any `CompletableFuture` methods with your own `Executor` (in that case, it would run according to the rules of said `Executor`).

Java 8 introduced a [common fork-join pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--), and the number of threads in this pool is usually equal to the number of cores on your machine.  When an async method is called without an executor, this fork-join pool is used as the executor.